# C# - Multiple Users from SQL Database for Login Form

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

So, I have a loginform where a user has to login to go into the mainform.
I have a database with a table created to store usernames and passwords, for logging in to the application.

If the user types in the correct username and password and clicks login, it should take him/her to the mainform. This I know how to do, but how do I get the usernames and passwords from the SQL database and check if they exist, and if they exist, is it the correct username for the correct password or vice versa?

Like I said, I created a SQL database to store usernames and passwords.
I then saved a user with the username and password both as "admin", just for testing purposes.

I tried this following code, but it isn't letting me log in even though I typed the correct username and password.

```
string username;
string password;

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"connectionString");
        SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT username, password FROM UsersPass WHERE username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'", con);
        con.Open();

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        SqlCeDataReader dtr = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (dtr.Read())
        {
            username = dtr["username"].ToString();
            password = dtr["password"].ToString();
            if (username == txtUsername.Text && password == txtPassword.Text)
            {
                Mainform frm = new Mainform();
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();     
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid credentials!\nPlease enter a valid username and password to continue.", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erorr", "Error");
    }
}
```

Forgive me if I'm missing something completely obvious, I'm fairly new to C#.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use SQL parameters rather than concatenating string for SQL.  And never, ever store passwords as plaintext.  And if there is an exception please share the full error message.

Comment: First, read up on Sql Injection. Second, read up on encryption. Third, read up on c#'s `using` keyword.

Comment: You dont need `if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)` If connection not open, then exception will be thrown.

Comment: I'm really not getting what you guys are saying. Like I said, I'm fairly new to C#, so I don't know most keywords and such. If you could be a little bit more specific, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Also you don't need to read `username=dtr["username"]`. `if(dtr.HasRows)` is enough. But you need to `dtr.Close();` and `con.Close()`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Can you edit that in the code I gave above and show me please? Thanks.

Comment: More specific about SQL injection. Let user type `';drop table userspass--`

Comment: Its very hard to read more than 5 or 6 DB related questions here and **not** see what SQL Parameters are and how to use them. Somewhat the same with the term `user passwords` and not find answers relating to hashing and salting PWs.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in debug mode? On which line does the program not do what you expect?  If you are new to C#, the debugger is the first thing to learn!  Also, as a slight tip, you should know that c# is case sensitive: "admin" is not the same as "Admin" or "ADMIN".  Are you sure you are entering the same case as is in the database?

Comment: Yes, I triple checked it. I was typing it correctly, but still it was not letting me log in. I tried it in debug mode too, still the same thing is happening. I just can't log in to the application.

Comment: Do you get "Error" or "Invalid credentials"?

Comment: @S.C. Im getting "Error". Not "Invalid credentials".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are getting the error message. Start by giving yourself more information on that. Either place a breakpoint in

```
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Erorr", "Error");
}
```

so you can see some details on the exception or change it to

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Erorr", ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

That will give you details on exactly why your application is failing and set you on a path towards getting things working like you want.

I suspect you have a bad connection string.

Edit: This particular issue was caused by sql server compact edition references being used in place of standard edition references. See the comments.

Comment: So then, the code that I'm currently using is correct? The one that I have mentioned in my post initially. I thought that my code was completely wrong. I will re-check the connection string now. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: The way to find out if your code is "correct" or not is to see what kind of error you are actually getting in that exception. I'm guessing it's related to the connection string but I could be completely off base. Your connection string might look correct but be in the wrong format for your connection library. Just see what the exception tells you.

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/zuWm9PE.png) is the exception I am getting. I am using the following connection string. `"Data Source=DELL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Users;Integrated Security=True"`

Comment: Are you actually using the compact edition of sql server? If you are, your connection string is targetting the wrong type of data source. If you aren't, try changing `SqlCeCommand` to `SqlCommand`, `SqlCeConnection` to `SqlConnection`, and `SqlCeDataReader` to `SqlDataReader`. Keep in mind even if that works you will get no output if you have bad credentials since you will never enter your while loop.

Comment: WOW! Changing everything to `Sql` instead of `SclCe` made it somehow work. Thank you very much, my problem is solved. Is there a way I can accept your comment as an answer?

Comment: Glad that solved your issue. Accepting the parent answer in this case is as good as accepting the comment since they are both by me. I will go ahead and update my original answer after that to make it clear what solved your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply another way in that:

```
           private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        string currentUserID=string.Empty;
                        SqlConnection connection= new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                        connection.Open();
                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                        command.CommandText = "SELECT UserID From UserPass WHERE username =@username AND password =@password";
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
                        command.Connection = connection;
                        object obj=command.ExecuteScalar();
                        if (obj!=null)
                        {
                            currentUserID= obj.ToString();
                            connection.Close();
                            Mainform frm = new Mainform();
                            frm.Show();
                            this.Hide();         
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        connection.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid credentials!\nPlease enter a valid username and password to continue.", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: It still is not letting me log in even though I typed in the correct username and password.

Comment: I tried this code. It's working. Please check your column name.@Akeel.F